# qt 6.3 firebase cpp sdk integration for android(cmake)

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, cmake, qt6

so I've been trying to integrate the newest cpp sdk(9.5) into my Qt6 cmake android application.
dependencies used

```
openjdk 11
ndk22.1.7171670
gradle 7.4(default from the qt android package template)
```

I've put the whole sdk dir inside my project.

here is the top level `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(kushok-client VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
if(ANDROID)

    include(${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}/android_openssl/CMakeLists.txt)

endif()

find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Quick REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Multimedia REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Network REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Charts REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Svg REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS Core5Compat REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS WebSockets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt6  COMPONENTS LinguistTools REQUIRED)

set(FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/libs/firebase_cpp_sdk")
add_subdirectory(${FIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR} bin/ EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
add_subdirectory(src/app)
```

and inside `src/app/CMakeLists.txt`

```
    if(ANDROID)
    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR android
        CACHE INTERNAL "")
endif()
qt_add_executable(appkushok-client
    cpp/core.h cpp/core.cpp
    assets/images/images.qrc
    assets/images/icons/icons.qrc
    assets/fonts/fonts.qrc
    cpp/main.cpp
)

target_include_directories(appkushok-client PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIR})
    qt_add_qml_module(appkushok-client
        URI KushokClient
        VERSION 1.0
        QML_FILES
            qml/main.qml
            js/utils.js
    )


set_target_properties(appkushok-client PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(ANDROID)
set_target_properties(appkushok-client PROPERTIES QT_ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS "${ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS}")
endif()

target_link_libraries(appkushok-client PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
Qt6::Core
Qt6::Multimedia
Qt6::Gui
Qt6::Network
Qt6::Charts
Qt6::Svg
Qt6::Core5Compat
Qt6::WebSockets
)

set(firebase_libs
firebase_messaging
firebase_auth
firebase_app
)
target_link_libraries(appkushok-client PRIVATE "${firebase_libs}")
target_compile_definitions(appkushok-client
    PRIVATE $<$<OR:$<CONFIG:Debug>,$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>>:QT_QML_DEBUG>)
```

then I followed the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android)

here is my build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
            // Add the following lines:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'  // Google Services plugin
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:18.1.0'

    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Services plugin

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}

android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake {
arguments "-DFIREBASE_CPP_SDK_DIR=$gradle.firebase_cpp_sdk_dir"
}

# Add the dependencies for the Firebase products you want to use in your app
# For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Firebase Realtime Database
apply from: "$gradle.firebase_cpp_sdk_dir/Android/firebase_dependencies.gradle"
firebaseCpp.dependencies {
auth
database
}


android {
    /*******************************************************
    * The following variables:
    * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
    * - androidCompileSdkVersion
    * - qtAndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
    *                   needed to build any Qt application
    *                   on Android.
    *
    * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
    * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
    * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
    *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()
    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
    ndkVersion androidNdkVersion

    // Extract native libraries from the APK
    packagingOptions.jniLibs.useLegacyPackaging true

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfig "en"
        minSdkVersion qtMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion
        ndk.abiFilters = qtTargetAbiList.split(",")
    }
}
```

and settings.gradle

```
def firebase_cpp_sdk_dir = System.getProperty('firebase_cpp_sdk.dir')

gradle.ext.firebase_cpp_sdk_dir = "$firebase_cpp_sdk_dir"
includeBuild "$firebase_cpp_sdk_dir"
```

I hardcoded the firebase cpp sdk path inside gradle.properties just to make sure it works

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2500m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
systemProp.firebase_cpp_sdk.dir=/home/sadeq/projects/kushok/mobile/kiosk-client-app-base/libs/firebase_cpp_sdk
```

I added the google-services.json inside my android package dir and my manifest contains this service

```
    <service android:name=".com.google.firebase.messaging.MessageForwardingService">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
    </service>
```

the projects compiles fine but crashes at runtime with this message

```
E firebase: Java class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp class is included in your app.
E firebase: clazz
F firebase: Java class com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp not found.  Please verify the AAR which contains the com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp class is included in your app.
F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 26087 (qtMainLoopThrea), pid 26062 (ppkushok_client)
```

it seems that the firebase java libraries were not imported,
I've tried putting the cpp sdk inside `ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/libs` but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had same runtime message and resolved it by adding following to the CMakeList.txt:

if(ANDROID)
set_property(TARGET "your_target_name" APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android
)
endif()

In you're case "your_target_name" is appkushok-client.

And build with Qt6.3.2. Problem was that my AndroidManifest.xml wasn't copied to the build directory sub dir android-build, but a default one from Qt.